# getting Error object not found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php

i'am making a website similar to stackoverflow website,and when i'am trying to access the signin.php or signup pages still getting an error say:
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404.

Note that i can access the other pages (index.php,questionDetails.php,...) without any problem

and then when i made a search in order to see why getting this error i found that  i'am missing something like .htaccess file.

so her how my project look like:

hirarchy:
[hirarchy of my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hw71.png)

navbar.php file:

```
<?php 
if (! isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    
}
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    .brand{
        font-family: fantasy;
    }
    .ulNavbar{
        display: inline-flex;
    }
</style>
<nav class="nav-wraper white ">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php" class="brand-logo brand black-text">UnivBatna</a>

        <a href="#" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target='mobile-links'>
            <i class="material-icons blue-text">menu</i>
        </a>
       
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down ulNavbar">
       <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>
            <img src="../imgs/yuna.jpg" alt="image" width='40px' height='50px' alt="" class="circle responsive-img img-profile">
             <p class="right black-text"> <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p>
                     
                     <button id="logout">LogOut</button>
                     <form action="../includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" name="logout" class="btn" value="Logout">
                     </form>
                <?php } else{ ?>

             <li><a href="./auth/Signin.php" class="btn brand">sign In</a></li>
             <li><a href="./auth/Signup.php" class="btn brand">sign up</a></li>

               <?php } ?>
        
    </ul>

    </div>
    
</nav>

<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-links">
   <li><a href="addquestion.php" class="btn blue">Add Question</a></li>
</ul>

</html>
```

index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include('./templates/header.php') ;?>
<?php include('./dashboard/Dashboard.php') ?>
<?php include('./templates/footer.php'); ?>


</html>
```

i think that i'am missing something here.
thanks already

Comment: Some file systems are case-sensitive. Your question mentions `signin.php` but your code is looking for `Signin.php`. I'd start there. I'd also recommend sticking to just lowercase, it just makes things easier to deal with. Also, `./auth/Signin.php` means "from the current directory/folder in the URL, look for a subfolder of `auth` with that file." If your URL includes things like "public" or "templates", that means it is trying to go to "/public/auth/Signin.php" and not "/auth/Signin.php"

Comment: For php structure / paths sometimes are different than you assume (long story) you can always test what sees your script https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir